# How to Insert a Figure Properly?

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm trying to insert a figure in my report, I get an error each time when I try this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=16cm,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{\string"C:/Users/Nectarys/Desktop/bur/rapports/tex/images/cu_global_initial\string".png}\hfill{}
\caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation global initial}
\end{figure}
```

Using this, I get a void rectangle containing the path.

Comment: Remove the `draft` option. I suggest you to save the `png` file on the same folder as your `tex` file and then you just use `{?????.png}`.

Comment: What is `\string`?

Comment: 1. Make sure the graphics you're trying to include is supported by the command you're issuing (latex, pdflatex, etc.). 2. Remove all those options in `\includegraphics` and add them one by one until the error occurs again. 3. Update your question with more information.

Comment: @HarishKumar Is something Lyx inserts!

Comment: @HarishKumar Presumably added in case `babel` has made `"` active.

Comment: @Sigur Really you shouldn't even need the extension, just `{<name>}`

Comment: So, did you have `draft` in the document class options or something, and did removing it solve this?